# Stripe Connect retrieve balance with PHP

Tags: php, json, stripe-payments

I am  building a Stripe connect integration with WordPress and I am trying to retrieve the balance for a connected account.

Here is my code so far:

```
// Show User Balance
function show_user_balance($uid){

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$user_id = $uid;

$connected_account_id = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'stripe_connect_id', true );

// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production!
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$balance = \Stripe\Balance::retrieve(
    ['stripe_account' => $connected_account_id]
  );

echo "Current Balance: ".$balance;

}
```

Echoing `$balance` returns the following JSON formatted string:

```
Current Balance: Stripe\Balance JSON: { "object": "balance", "available": [ { "amount": 0, "currency": "usd", "source_types": { "card": 0 } } ], "instant_available": [ { "amount": 0, "currency": "usd", "source_types": { "card": 0 } } ], "livemode": false, "pending": [ { "amount": 0, "currency": "usd", "source_types": { "card": 0 } } ] }
```

I want to echo the amount of the available balance. I already tried using `json_decode` function set to true. It returns an array of objects and I have tried both `print_r` and `var_dump` without successful results.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted [in the Stripe API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance/balance_object?lang=php#balance_object-available) the Balance object has an "available" and "pending" property, each of which is an array of balances in different currencies. One simple way to print out available balance in USD is:

```
foreach ($balance->available as $bal) {
  if ($bal->currency == "usd")
    echo "{$bal->amount} {$bal->currency} available\n";
}

foreach ($balance->pending as $bal) {
  if ($bal->currency == "usd")
    echo "{$bal->amount} {$bal->currency} pending\n";
}
```

Of course, you want to format the money correctly for your locale. And, if you expect payments in multiple currencies you'll have to print out those as well. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution worked fine. Didn't cross my mind that  I had to loop through the object. I was trying to decode it but it is nested. I am only using USD for this project so I can just echo out pending and available amounts. Thanks again!